# ¿Cómo agregar texto por debajo de imagen HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Quiero poner el Id="boton" debajo de la imagen que esta mas arriba pero me lo coloca al lado. 
**¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?**

```
<div  id="lube" >
  <img style="width:500px;" src="Img/Lubricante.jpg" align="left";>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="boton" type="button">Lista de Lubricantes en baldes</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una solución rápida: **elimina `align="left"`**. Ese atributo es el que hace que la imagen *flote* hacia la izquierda y que el botón aparezca a su derecha. El código con el cambio (pulsa en "Página completa" para verlo):

```html
<div  id="lube" >
  <img style="width:500px;" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
</div>
<div>
  <button id="boton" type="button">Lista de Lubricantes en baldes</button>
</div>
```

Otro buen motivo para eliminar ese atributo es que [a partir de HTML5 se considera obsoleto](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html) y ha sido desechado del estándar; puede que siga funcionando, pero no es lo correcto (deberías usar CSS y la propiedad `float:left` en su lugar).

Answer (score 0):

Que mas, es sencillo, mira este código y prueba tu mismo, no veo que pidas estilos ni nada por el estilo, revisa esto

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://rohitashv.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/kodingen.jpg" >
  <br>
  <button>
    Boton debajo
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, en lugar de dejar el código en un enlace a un servicio externo puedes dejarlo acá mismo como code snippet (fragmento HTML/JavaScript/CSS)

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta @CarlosMuñoz, gracias por la recomendacion