# Mostrar una galeria con datos mySQL + PHP + css

Tags: php, mysql, css

Estoy intentando hacer una galería de imágenes que muestra datos que tengo almacenados en la base de datos mediante php, pero no consigo aclararme sobre como hacerlo.
Mi idea es que se muestren de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero se me muestran así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es decir, me gustaría que saliese el enlace a detalles y los nombres debajo de cada foto, y que pudiese hacer por ejemplo 3 columnas y 3 filas... y no se muy bien como hacerlo.
este es el trozo de código donde hago el foreach (php) que me muestra todos los datos de la bd:

```
 <?php foreach ($mostrar as $resultado){ ?>
        <div class="container">
           
            
            <img src="<?php echo $resultado->img ?>">
            <div class="name"><h5><?php echo $resultado->nombre; ?></h5></div>
                <div class="detalles">
                
      
                <div class="hipervinculo">  <a href="#"> Detalles</a> </div>
                </div>
           <?php } ?> 
        </div>
```

CÓDIGO CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #fdfcfb 0%, #e2d1c3 100%);
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    display: flex;
}


img {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-right:30px; 
    max-height:200px; 
    max-width:400px; 
    object-fit:contain;
    align-items:  "left";
}

img:hover { /*efecto al pasar ratón x encima*/
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
```

Comment: eso ya seria usar css para las posiciones e ir probando como queda mejor, yo en su dia hice algo parecido a esto https://javiergraya.000webhostapp.com/examen-html-css-2019-2020/index.html te dejo mi plantilla de css https://javiergraya.000webhostapp.com/examen-html-css-2019-2020/index.css

Comment: @JavierG.Raya estoy en ello pero no se ya a que aplicarlo exactamente para conseguir lo que quiero

Comment: debes crearte un css por ejemplo tu div class="name" pues a traves de ese name lo pones en el css ``#name { vertical-align: text-bottom; }`` y se te debería bajar, para mas información ve al siguiente enlace : https://ruvic.es/alinear-el-texto-con-imagenes-en-css-arriba-en-el-medio-o-abajo/

Comment: Te dejo otro foro para la imagen : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7668/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-texto-por-debajo-de-imagen-html-css

Comment: Y mas información https://www.ribosomatic.com/articulos/agregar-descripcion-parte-inferior-imagenes-web-con-css/ con todo esto creo que serás capaz de sacarlo, espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Si añades el código **CSS** que tienes hecho hasta ahora, sería más fácil de ayudar.

Comment: @DBE listo, ya está añadido

Answer (score 4):

El fallo que tenías con **flex** es que por defecto usa `flex-direction: row;`

Si leas en el manual el comportamiento de row nos dice:

> **row:**
> El eje principal del contenedor flexible está definido para ser el mismo que la dirección del texto. Los puntos principales de inicio y final son los mismos que la dirección del contenido

Por eso te esta alineando tu imagen con el texto. Te dejo un completo guia de como usar [FLEXBOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

En mi ejemplo uso `display:grid`, que veo mejor para este caso.
Te he dejado también un `@mediascreen` para que veas como podrías cambiar el total de 4 a 2 según ancho pantalla, así lo puedes personalizar.

Aquí una guía de cómo usar [GRID](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #fdfcfb 0%, #e2d1c3 100%);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color linear;
}


/* Usamos GRID */

.container {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container img {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  align-items: "left";
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.container img:hover {
  /*efecto al pasar ratón x encima*/
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container .detalles {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: .5rem 0 1rem 0;
}

.contenido .video_camara {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.detalles .titulo_detalles {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.detalles .hipervinculo_detalles {
  color: black;
}

.detalles .hipervinculo_detalles:hover {
  color: blue;
}


/* Responsive design, ya lo dejas a tu gusto */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <span class="video_camara">&#128249;</span>
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <span class="video_camara">&#128249;</span>
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <span class="video_camara">&#128249;</span>
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <span class="video_camara">&#128249;</span>
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contenido">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
    />

    <div class="detalles">
      <h5 class="titulo_detalles">Titulo</h5>
      <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#"> Detalles</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tu **PHP** debería quedar así:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php 
    foreach ($mostrar as $resultado) : ?>

        <div class="contenido">

            <img src="<?php echo $resultado->img ?>" alt='' />

            <div class="detalles">
              <!-- optional camara -->
              <span class="video_camara">&#128249;</span>
              <h5 class="titulo_detalles"><?php echo $resultado->nombre; ?></h5>
              <a class="hipervinculo_detalles" href="#">Detalles</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        
    <?php 
    endforeach; 
    ?> 
</div>
```